# Harmonic measure of a punctured disc

Tags: real-analysis, cv.complex-variables, brownian-motion, potential-theory

Let $D$ be a disc in $\mathbb{C}\cong\mathbb{R}^2 $ and $z_0$ a fixed point of $D$. Is the harmonic measure for $V=D\setminus\{z_0\}$ known? Any reference would also be  welcome.

Comment: should be same as harmonic measure for $D$

Comment: Would you please explain. I don't see why?

Comment: brownian motion has probability $0$ of hitting any particular point. look up brownian motion interpretation of harmonic measure and 'polar set'.

Comment: And in general, irregular boundary points do not influence the harmonic measure.